# Installing google app engine launcher on Mac with M1

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, installation

Is there a way to install GAE launcher on MacBook Pro with M1 chip?

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine Launcher has been deprecated ([this was done about 2 years ago](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration)). First, Google stopped releasing updates for it but it still worked which is why some folks (I fall into that category) kept the launcher and were still using it.

Sometime (about 2020 or so), GAE changed to using Cloud Build for deployment which meant that Google App Engine launcher could no longer be used for deploying code (GAE Launcher used `appcfg.py` whereas cloud builder needs to use `gcloud app deploy`). This effectively killed GAE Launcher.

This led to us building a replacement for GAE Launcher - [NoCommandLine](https://nocommandline.com) - but it hasn't been explicitly tested on MacBook Pro with M1 though we believe it should work since it is at least IOS 10+. You can try it and let us know via the feedback form how you fared.